# How do I get a list of members in a Python module, or how should I create plugins?

Tags: plugins, python-3.x

I'm writing a sort of dashboard-esque program in Python to make tasks that I do frequently here at work a little better/easier.

What I currently have set up is an `actions` module. `actions` contains an `actionlist` that is a list of classes. Each of my classes has a `.title`, `.icon` (base-64 encoded string for use with tkinter.PhotoImage), and a `.action` function.

Using tkinter I create a new button for each of these actions, with the appropriate icon, text, and the command of the button set to the `.action`. So far it works quite nicely, but if I want to create a new action, I have to go into my `actions` module, create a new class, and then put that class in my `actionlist`.

What I would like to do is be able to dynamically generate this actionlist based on what files are present in my module. So I would like to have something like this:

```
actions/
        __init__.py
        someaction.py
        do_another_thing.py
        do_all_the_things.py
        chop_down_the_tree_with_a_herring.py
```

And whenever I would like to create a new action, I just put a `.py` script in my `actions` folder and then it would automagically generate the list of actions for me, however I can't seem to find any good way of creating this list. I've thought of using something like `os.listdir` to get the list of files, but neither that or the other methods of introspection (`dir`, and `inspect.getmembers`) seemed to have quite what I wanted. Of course, it's possible that I just missed the features that I need.

In any case, pointers in the right direction would be great. Thanks!

### SOLUTION:

Lennart's solution, with some slight adaptations worked for me.

Inside my `__init__.py` I have the following code:

```
plugins = []
__all__ = [
           'do_all_the_things',
           'do_another_thing',
           'someaction',
           'chop_down_the_tree_with_a_herring',
           'seek_the_grail',
          ]
```

Then inside each of my plugins I have something like this:

```
from actions import plugins

class SeekTheGrail:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = 'We Seek The Grail'
        self.icon = b'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'
    def action(self):
        print('I am Arthur, King of the Britons!')

plugins.append(SeekTheGrail())
```

and now I just have to modify the `__all__` collection when I want to add or remove the actions from loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to create plugins is to have a plugin registry, and register plugins there. This can be done from the amazingly simple, like just defining a global list in a module:

```
plugins = []
```

And then registering the plugins with:

```
class APlugin(object):
    blahblah

from themodule import plugins
plugin.add(APlugin())
```

This can be made more flexible by having types of plugins and registering them with a name etc. But then you are on the path to complexity, and then you might want to take a look at the [Zope Component Architecture](http://www.muthukadan.net/docs/zca.html), which simply speaking is a very powerful system for making your application pluggable.

It should be noted that in any case it's best to have a list of what plugins should be activated instead of auto-discovering them. This can be as simple as a list in a text file or a setting in a config file. This enables you to easily activate and disactivate the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
actions = {}
for filename in os.listdir('somepath/actions'):
    actions[filename] = __import__('actions.'+filename)
for name,class in actions:
    createButton(name,class)
```

Where in the createButton you create your tk_inter button and assign it the functions from the class. The important bit i suppose is that you can use `__import__` to import a class using its string name and save it as a variable.